# How do I insert a record with a mysql SET type?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wanted to ask how I insert a record with the mysql SET type.
Lets assume the following table:

```
user_id   
int(8)
```

and

```
user_rights
set('conversation','offer','turnover','financial','admin');
```

How would my INSERT query be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: @juergend If I'm not mistaken, an enum and a set are not quite the same type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes around your choices ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html)). You can set multiple choices :

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, user_rights) VALUES 
(1, 'conversation,offer,turnover,financial,admin'),
(2, 'conversation,financial'),
(3, 'conversation'),
(4, 'conversation,offer,financial');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example :

```
INSERT INTO yourTable SET user_id=7, user_rights='admin';
```

See [INSERT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html).